# Basic Vim Installation, from Source Code

Tags: python, vim

Tried installing Vim 7.3 so I first installed Mercurial, which allowed me to clone vim source code off Googlecode. This was done successfully.

Problem started from here:

```
cd vim/src
./configure --enable-pythoninterp --with-features=huge -prefix=$HOME/opt/vim
```

which drew this response from the terminal:

```
configure: loading cache auto/config.cache
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for cc... no
checking for cl.exe... no
configure: error: in `/Users/JayEdge/vim/src':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Tried looking at config.log (in my case it was auto/config.log) but I'm not sure what to look out for.

Background: I've checked that Xcode is installed properly, and gcc.vim was found inside the route vim/runtime/compiler. Should I move this (or duplicate this) into another folder? If so, which folder to move it into?

Comment: You need to run `echo $PATH` from the shell where you're running `configure`, and confirm it contains `/usr/bin` (or wherever the Xcode C compiler lives).  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6796982/212858) question might help too.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not using [macports](http://macports.org) or [homebrew](http://mxcl.github.com/homebrew/)?

Comment: Just download MacVim, puth the `mvim` script somewhere in your `$PATH` and go back to actual work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like Karoly said, you need a c compiler. Since it looks like you are running OSX (based on your xcode comment I would suggest grabbing the OSX-GCC installer at the following site:

```
https://github.com/kennethreitz/osx-gcc-installer
```

I would also look into grabbing [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) for installing things like vim.

Cheers,
Sean

Comment: Problem has been solved and here's to share with anyone if they have the same problems, specifically for people who install xCode via the app store after March 2012. (Credits to my Python Mentor, Martin) Xcode from the app store currently only allows you to download the IDE, which is not what we want. What we want is the Apple Developer Tools, which you can get via https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ after signing up as a Apple Developer. Search for "Command Line Tools, late March 2012", install it and the configure command earlier should work properly.

Comment: Jason, that link I posted was a link to the command line tools but they don't require you to go though all the hoopla of signing up as an Apple developer. Apple actually reached out to Kenneth Reitz the pythonista who developed those tools to partner and have them as part of the apple developer tools. If you are interested, Kenneth writes about it on his blog.

Comment: Hi Sean, thank you very much; I'd check that out. (I'd love to vote up your answer but unfortunately I have insufficient reputation to do so)

Answer (score 1):

> no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH

That's a pretty clear error message, you need to install a compiler, if you haven't done sone. 
[Install gcc](http://google.com/search?q=mac%20install%20gcc).

If you already installed `gcc` you have to add the path so configure can find it, eg:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/bin"
```

Comment: `yum`? `apt-get`?  I think he's on a mac.

Comment: you're probably right, he has a mac path (`/Users/`...), updated.

Comment: Hey, indeed. I'm using a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved and here's to share with anyone if they have the same problems, specifically for people who install xCode via the app store after March 2012. (Credits to my Python Mentor, Martin)

Xcode from the app store currently only allows you to download the IDE, which is not what we want. What we want is the Apple Developer Tools, which you can get via https://developer.apple.com/xcode/ after signing up as a Apple Developer. Search for "Command Line Tools, late March 2012", install it and the configure command earlier should work properly.

Otherwise, you may refer to Sean's answer earlier.

FYI, I do intend to install homebrew but as a beginner, compiling it from source code is a great way of picking up some basics, interact with some basic syntax (or learn to parse them).

Answer (score 0):

you can try it:

```
 yum install gcc
```